# Creating chlid class object in parent class

Tags: c#, oop, object, inheritance, subclass

I have two classes a parent class and child. what I really want to find away so ,I can create an object of child class in parent class. I tired but compiler throw exception here is my code.

```
   class b  { 
        private c obj;
        public b()
        {
            obj=new c();
        }
        public void show()
        {

            obj.show();
        }
        }
        class c : b{ 
        public void show()
        {
        Console.WriteLine("working ");
        }
        }
  b object=new b();
  b.show();
```

Is there a way to create child class object in Parent class.

Comment: What "exception" does it throw?

Comment: process terminated due to unexpected error

Comment: Compilers don't throw exceptions - they report compilation errors. Your current code wouldn't compile as you can't use `object` as an identifier, to start with. It's not clear whether that's your *actual* code though. It would help if you'd show a short but complete example, including compilation errors, while following normal C# naming conventions and performing appropriate source formatting to make it easy for us to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
class b  { 
    private c obj;
    public b()
    {

    }
    public void show(c o)
    {
        obj = o;
        obj.show();
    }
    }
    class c : b{ 
    public void show()
    {
    Console.WriteLine("working ");
    }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            c o=new c();
            b bo = new b();
            bo.show(o);
            o.show();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Strictly speaking that doesn't answer the question. It doesn't create a child object in the parent class, and it doesn't say anything about whether it is possible or not.

Comment: I'm pass child class object on run time and set it . and you create object at that point. In my point of view there is no major difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a child object from the parent class, but not in the constructor. If you do that, the child object (which is also a parent) will create another child, which will create another child, and so on. You have made an infinite loop.

You can create a child object from a method in the parent class. Example:

```
public class Parent {

  private Child _child;

  public void CreateChild() {
    _child = new Child();
  }

  public void Show() {
    _child.Show();
  }

}

public class Child : Parent {

  public void Show() {
    Console.WriteLine("Working");
  }

}

Parent p = new Parent();
p.CreateChild();
p.Show();
```